# How can I access a date typed field from an ExtJS JSonStore?

Tags: date, types, extjs4, field, jsonstore

I've been trying to retrieve a date value and an integer value from the database, using the following code:

```
var l_alsChampsMois, l_stoDonneesMois;

    try {
        l_alsChampsMois = [
          {name: "date_mois", type: "date", dateFormat: "Y-m-d"},
          {name: "indice", type: "integer"}
        ];

        l_stoDonneesMois = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
            fields: l_alsChampsMois,
            autoLoad: false,
            proxy: {
                type: "ajax",
                url: "/commun/req_sql/req_ind_per_mois.php",
                reader: {
                    type: "json",
                    root: "rows"
                },
                // some configs to use jsFiddle echo service (you will remove them)
                actionMethods: {
                    read: "POST"
                },
               extraParams: {
                    key:"test"
                }
            },
            listeners: {
                load: function(objStore, alsLignes, blnOk, objOptions) {
window.alert("Mois fin : " + objStore.getAt(0).get("date_mois"));
                }
            }
        });

    l_stoDonneesMois.load({params:            {
                                p_idsoc:    l_strIdSociete,
                                p_mois:        l_datDebut.getMonth() + 1,   
                                // getMonth renvoie 0 pour janvier, etc. 
                                p_annee:    l_datDebut.getFullYear(),
                                p_debut:    1,
                                p_etape:    1
                                } 
                            });
```

with l_strIdSociete and l_datDebut being variables previously assigned and /commun/req_sql/req_ind_per_mois.php the PHP page that retrieves the data and converts it to JSON.

It seems to work fine (indeed, Firebug tells me the load does retrieve a data structure with "date_mois" and "indice" containing the values I expect them to), only the window.alert returns undefined. If I replace "date_mois" with "indice", it returns the expected value for "indice".

I've tried to use objStore.getAt(0).getData()["date_mois"], to no avail.

My only clue about this is that "date_mois" in the data structure shown by Firebug is an Object, but even so it shouldn't be undefined, now should it? I looked up http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-type that wasn't exactly forthcoming with straight answers.

So what did I do wrong there?

Comment: Can you make dump of objStore.getAt(0)? Then look at **raw** field to make sure that you've really got needed data.

Comment: Interesting question. Yesterday Firebug wouldn't debug for some reason, so I had to make do with multiple window.alert() messages (but I didn't think of the **raw** field). Enough rambling, the **raw** field has: 
Object { 
  date_mois = { date="2012-11-30 00:00:00", timezone_type=3, timezone="UTC" } ,
  indice = "23"
}
So it seems the needed data is there.

Comment: Maybe i'm wrong, but you think ext js can recognize your date as object of 3 fields? I never saw this before. Send time as unix timestamp, it works anyway.

Comment: @Prodigy: That's the point: I'm surprised that it cannot give me the object the JSON returns (and that the **raw** field holds). Can you please give me an example of sending time as Unix timestamp from a PHP source, please?

Comment: @Vyacheslav Voronchuk: the JSON value given by Firebug is the same as the **raw** field. Do you need more information? If so, what?

Answer (score 0):

If you need current time you can use php **time** function(note: it returns seconds, JS uses milliseconds), in another case you need to convert by **mktime** function.

Comment: Fine, thanks. That's beside the main point, but it may come in handy at some point.